# Inno Setup - Show MsgBox and click 'OK' go back to previous page

Tags: inno-setup, back-button, pascalscript

I have 'A' page `TOutputMsgWizardPage` and 'B' page `TInputQueryWizardPage`.

When I click B page's 'Next', show a `MsgBox` including 'OK' and 'Cancel' button. When I click 'OK', going back to 'A' page.

Could it happen?

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Page sequence is: WelcomePage => OutputMsgPage => InputQueryPage => SelectDirPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TWizardPage.OnNextButtonClick` to handle *"Next"* button clicks.

When handling the *"Next"* button, you can simulate a press on the *"Back"* button to go back to the previous page instead.

```pascal
[Code]

var
  OutputMsgPage: TOutputMsgWizardPage;
  InputQueryPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function InputQueryPageNextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if MsgBox('Go back?', mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDOK then
  begin
    WizardForm.BackButton.OnClick(WizardForm.BackButton);

    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  OutputMsgPage :=
    CreateOutputMsgPage(wpWelcome, 'Output page', '', 'Output page');

  InputQueryPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(OutputMsgPage.ID, 'Input page', '', 'Input page');
  InputQueryPage.OnNextButtonClick := @InputQueryPageNextButtonClick;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, I think your solution is pretty helpful for me. Thanks! I will try continually to check if any other problem happen.